# Unable to svn import but can svn checkout

Tags: svn

So On Windows, my svn repository is at C:\Code\SVN and contains a number of projects.
Have an svnserver running using

```
svnserve --root c:\code\svn --daemon
```

I can check out existing projects using

```
svn checkout svn://localhost/projectname
```

But when I try and import a new preoject into the repository using

```
svn import . svn://localhost/ -m "initial repos"
```

It just complains

```
svn: No repository found in 'svn://localhost'
```

I get the same problem if I try to use the SmartSVN tool instead, how can this be.

EDIT:Trying suggestion below was no better

```
svn import . svn://localhost/newProjectName -m "balblabal" 
svn: No repository found in 'svn://localhost/newProjectName'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One svn repository has the following directories: conf, dav, db, hooks, locks. If you have several folders with such subfolders then you have several repositories. Command `svn import` needs an already created repository. If you want to create new repository then use `svnadmin create`.

Comment: yes you are exactly correct, there are multiple repositories below here and I had completed forgotten about svn create, now working, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be

```
svn import . svn://localhost/newProjectName -m "balblabal"
```

?

Comment: are you sure that svn://localhost/ is really a repository root?

Comment: No that was the problem, it was just a folder that contained repository roots

Comment: Oh, my "repository root" in fact means the root directory of a svn repository, while it seems that you means a root directory that stores multiple repositories...  :P

Answer (score 0):

I think that starting `svnserve --root c:\code\svn --daemon` leads to a process that serves all repositories. So when using an svn client, you should address in which repository you want to do something. See for an example the ["svn import in svn red book"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.importing). If your command would succeed, all files and directories located in your current directory would be imported at the root of your subversion repository (which is a bad idea either).